# how can i resize frame of UIViewController when rotate screen?

Tags: iphone, ipad, uiviewcontroller, orientation

I'm developing a program based iPad.
I created new modal UIViewController as formsheet mode not full screen.
And to resize the view, i used following codes.
...

```
MyController* controller = [[MyController alloc] init];

controller.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;

[self presentModalViewController : controller animated: YES];

UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation;

if ( UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(orientation) )
    controller.view.superview.frame = CGRectMake(200, 100, 350, 600);
else
    controller.view.superview.frame = CGRectMake(100, 200, 600, 350);
```

...

in MyController, i taked following codeds as didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation.

```
- (void) didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation
{
    UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation;
    if ( fromInterfaceOrientation == orientation )
        return;
    if ( UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(orientation) )
    {
        self.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 350, 600);
        self.view.superview.frame = CGRectMake(200, 100, 940, 628);
    }
    else
    {
        self.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 600, 350);
        self.view.superview.frame = CGRectMake(100, 200, 600, 350);
    }
}
```

but when rotate screen, the view don't be resized and width and height of superview  has unexpect value.
please help my problem.

Answer (score 0):

try to debug it and see what orientation you get in fact.

Did you try like this?

```
- (void) didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation
{

    if ( UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(fromInterfaceOrientation) )
    {
        self.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 350, 600);
        self.view.superview.frame = CGRectMake(200, 100, 940, 628);
    }
    else
    {
        self.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 600, 350);
        self.view.superview.frame = CGRectMake(100, 200, 600, 350);
    }
}
```

Also note that there are two portairt orientations..